# Stored procedures with output parameters using SqlQuery in the DbContext API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4, dbcontext

I coulndt return output parameter from the query,here is the my codes

```
  ETEntities en = new ETEntities();


           var prm_TotalRecords = new SqlParameter
           {
               ParameterName = "totalrow",
                 SqlDbType=System.Data.SqlDbType.Int
                 ,Direction= ParameterDirection.Output

           };

           var prm_start = new SqlParameter
           {
               ParameterName = "page",
               Value = start,
               SqlDbType=System.Data.SqlDbType.Int

           };
           var prm_sort= new SqlParameter
           {
               ParameterName = "msort",
               SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar,
               Value = sort

           };
           var prm_limit = new SqlParameter
           {
               ParameterName = "size",
               SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Int,
               Value = limit

           };


           string sql = "SP_PRODUCT_GET_PAGING @size,@page,@msort,@totalrow out";
           object[] parameters = new object[] { prm_limit,prm_start,prm_sort,prm_TotalRecords};
           var data = en.Database.SqlQuery<Urun>(sql,parameters);
          // TotalRecords = (int)prm_TotalRecords.Value;//here is the give null error
           TotalRecords = 3;
        return data;
```

everrything is work fine if set 3  to TotalRecords manually,but this part gives me null error. `TotalRecords = (int)prm_TotalRecords.Value;`
how can I return the this value ,thank you

Comment: you tried to call the stored procedure via sql server console to verify @totalrow value ?

Comment: Yep i tried and it gives me correct value

Comment: Try to read data (Urun) before reading output param

Comment: Ok but how,it seems not possiale on my secario

Comment: try calling ToList() or First() on your data